# Как получить LocalDate используя формат "yyyy"?

Tags: время, java-8, формат, localdate

Что-то не могу сообразить...

Есть год, например, `1933`.

Есть `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy");`

Пытаюсь преобразовать `LocalDate.parse("1933", formatter);`, выдаётся ошибка:

> ```
> Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {Year=1933},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed.
> ```

Как мне правильно преобразовать числовой год в объект `LocalDate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете создать объект `LocalDate` не указав параметры день и месяц. Поэтому такой паттерн `"yyyy"`  может только парситься форматтером. Чтобы получить объект `LocalDate` вы можете указать день, например:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ORDINAL_DATE;
LocalDate.parse("1933-001", formatter);
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо.
Я добавляю к году 01 01. Двоякотолкуемо, но не критично. :)

Comment: 001 - это первый день года, то есть 1 января.